Help identifying Neutral Wire
I am trying to replace the 3 way switch on the right with a Kasa 3 way dimmer.
Usually the neutral is a bundle of white wires.  In this case I am not sure.



You have old style switch loops/white travellers and no neutral/s.  Those white wires should be marked with dark colours so they are not mistaken as neutrals.  Some smart switches can use ground in these cases if in the instructions, usually special made switches for older switch loop cases.

@crip659 There is no evidence shown to indicate that this is a switch loop. If the other 3-way switch has only a /3 cable connected, that would be proof.

The general problem is that "dumb" 3-way switches don't use neutral, but standard cables always include white and a 3-way switch requires 3 wires between the switches.
That all should mean one of the following in the 3-wire cable between the switches:

Two travelers (black and red) + neutral (white)
Two travelers (black and red) + hot (white, marked with another color)
Two travelers + switched hot (colors arbitrary)

and there are probably some other possibilities, plus the second case often ends up with arbitrary colors, which isn't all that bad.
However, the first combination is an absolute - if you have neutral in the 3-way switch 3-wire cable you must assign it to neutral.
Related to this is that there is normally a 2-wire cable at each end of the circuit. Comparing to the three combinations above, the likely configurations are:

First switch box: hot (black)/neutral (white), second switch box: switched hot (black)/neutral (white)
First switch box: two cables, hot (black)/neutral (white) and switched hot (black)/neutral (white) or one cable: hot (white)/switched hot (black) and in any case, second switch box: no extra cable

At first glance, one possibility that may be the actual situation is:

Two-wire cable is an old switch loop with hot (white)/switched hot (black). Which makes the white/red wire nut OK except that the white should be marked with black tape or paint to indicate it is hot. But since that last detail is often ignored, we'll assume it for the moment.
Three-wire cable is hot (red), travelers (black and white).

However, it is possible that the switch loop is not "unmarked" but "backwards". In which case the two-wire cable is hot (black)/switched hot (white) and the three-wire cable is switched hot (red), travelers (black and white). Which is a totally different configuration from the standpoint of attaching hot and switched hot to a new switch.
The way to definitively identify each wire and cable is to:

Get similar pictures of the 3-way switch on the other end of the 3-wire cable. If there are other cables in that box that will complicate things, but possibly clarify things - and in any case we need to know what is there to be sure.
Test the 2-wire cable by disconnecting it from the 3-wire cable and 3-way switch in order to (carefully) determine which wire, if any, is hot.

But what is pretty clear is that at least this box does not have neutral in it for this 3-way switch circuit unless things are really miswired.

Thank you for the detailed response.  I just looked at the Kasa kit closer.  The "satellite" switch does not require a neutral!  I just was going on how all the single poles switches are configured.

The catch is that you can have situations where both switches have neutral (I am 99% certain you do not have that) or where one switch has neutral (which might be the case for you, but can't tell from just this switch) or where neither switch has neutral (which I suspect is your situation, but again can't tell for sure).

There is an absolutely no evidence that this is a switch loop. It’s a 3-way switch with a /2 cable and a /3 cable connected. The /3 obviously goes to the other switch, and the /2 could be line or load - with black being hot and white neutral. Simplest explanation is that it was wired by somebody who made a mistake and used the white wire in the /3 as a traveler instead of the red.
